# For $p\geqslant 1$ there is some $f\in L^1$ s.t. $\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }|\hat f(k)|^p=\infty $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Im having trouble with this exercise.

> Show that for any chosen $p\geqslant 1$ there is some $f\in L^1((-\pi,\pi])$ such that $\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }|\hat f(k)|^p=\infty $

There
$$
\hat f(k):=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi }^{\pi }f(x)e^{-ikt}\,\mathrm d t\tag1
$$
is the classical Fourier coefficient.

Let $f(z):=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac1{k^r} z^k$, then $f\in L^2(\partial \Bbb D )$ when $r>1/2$, and because for any space of finite measure we knows that $L^p\subset L^q$ for $p>q$, then $f\in L^1(\partial \Bbb D )$ also and $\sum_{k\in \Bbb Z }|\hat f(k)|^p=\infty $ whenever $rp\leqslant 1$, what happens when $p\in[1,1/r]$, and so we proved the case for all $p\in[1,2)$.

However Im having trouble finding a way to show the statement for $p\geqslant 2$. I tried to find some lower bound for $|\hat f(k)|^p$ (or it sum) using Jensen's inequality and similar ideas but I dont find something useful.  Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for $0 < \alpha < 1$ you let $f(t) = |t|^{\alpha - 1}$ then a direct calculation shows that for some constant $c$ one has 
$\hat{f}(k) = c|k|^{-\alpha} + o(|k|^{-\alpha})$ for $k > 0$ and $\hat{f}(k) = \bar{c}|k|^{-\alpha} + o(|k|^{-\alpha})$ for $k < 0$. Thus taking $\alpha$ close enough to $0$ will give an example for any given $p$.

Some details on the calculation: by definition one has
$$\hat{f}(k) = {1 \over 2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|t|^{\alpha - 1}e^{-ikt} dt$$
Say $k > 0$. Then changing variables to $u = tk$ this equals
$${1 \over 2\pi} k^{-\alpha}\int_{-k\pi}^{k\pi}|u|^{\alpha - 1}e^{-iu} du$$
Since the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u|^{\alpha - 1}e^{-iu} du$ converges to some limit $L$ this equals 
$${L \over 2\pi} k^{-\alpha} - k^{-\alpha}{1 \over 2\pi} \int_{|u| > 2k\pi}|u|^{\alpha - 1}e^{-iu} du$$
Again using that the improper integral converges, the error term is $o(k^{-\alpha})$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Could you give some explanation about formulation of $\hat{f}(k)$? In fact, I did similar approach and get $\int_0 ^{(k\pi)^\frac{1}{\beta}} e^{-i |x|^\beta} dx$ for coefficient, but I could not find nice argument for bound that integral.

Comment: I added some details. The improper integral converges by some standard methods which I didn't include. Hopefully this suffices.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Maybe I should look for mathematical physics texts or something else.

Comment: I just found that your integral clearly converges. (Maybe cauchy contour integral technique will do.) Seems to my way of changing variables were not that great. //  Thanks again and +1.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Your limit argument is awesome..(Well, at least to me.) It did help.

Comment: indeed the integral can be stated just for the cosine function because the imaginary part is odd. Amazing argument

Answer (score 1):

By the closed graph theorem, it suffices to prove that there is no $C > 0$ satisfying $\sum_k |\widehat{f}(k)|^p \leq C \cdot \|f\|_{L^1}^p$ for all $f \in L^1$.

To see this, consider the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) $F_n$. It satisfies $F_n \geq 0$ and $\|F_n\|_{L^1} = \int F_n \, d x \leq \kappa$, with $\kappa$ independent of $n$. It thus suffices to show that $\sum_k |\widehat{F_n}(k)|^p \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. To see this, simply note that
$$
\widehat{F_n}(k) = 1 - \frac{|k|}{n} \quad \text{for} \quad |k| \leq n .
$$